# It is not inserting questionid in answer db table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am having trouble being able to insert `QuestionId` into the `Answer` Table.

The `Question` inserts with no problem, but I am trying to retrieve the `QuestionId` from the `Question` Table which is an auto increment into the `Answer` Table by finding the `SessionId` and `QuestionNo` that particular `QuestionId` belongs to. Instead it keeps displaying `0` for `QuestionId` when inserted into `Answer` Table.

Now I know the query which tries to perform the select for each `QuestionId` from the `Question` Table is correct as this has been tested. I think the problem is where I have placed my code but I am not sure?

Here are the db tables:

Question Table

```
QuestionId (auto)  SessionId  QuestionNo
4                  2          1
5                  2          2
6                  2          3
```

Answer Table at moment:

```
AnswerId (auto)  QuestionId  Answer
7                0           A
8                0           C
9                0           A
10               0           B
11               0           True
```

What Answer Table should look like:

```
AnswerId (auto)  QuestionId  Answer
7                4           A
8                4           C
9                5           A
10               5           B
11               6           True
```

Below is the code:

```
 $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionNo) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}

 $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";
if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}



//make sure both prepared statements succeeded before proceeding
if( $insert && $insertanswer)
{
    $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');
    $c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
    {


            $insert->bind_param("ii", $sessionid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);

            $insert->execute();

            if ($insert->errno) 
            {
                // Handle query error here
                echo __LINE__.': '.$insert->error;
                break 1;
            }
}

        $results = $_POST['value'];
        foreach($results as $id => $value) 
        {
            $answer = $value;

            $lastID = $id;

            $questionidquery = "SELECT QuestionId FROM Question WHERE (QuestionNo = ? AND SessionId = ?)";

        if (!$questionidstmt = $mysqli->prepare($questionidquery)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
          echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
        }


        // Bind parameter for statement
        $questionidstmt->bind_param("ii", $lastID, $sessionId);

        // Execute the statement
        $questionidstmt->execute();

                    if ($questionidstmt->errno) 
                    {
                        // Handle query error here
                        echo __LINE__.': '.$questionidstmt->error;
                        break 2;
                    }

        // This is what matters. With MySQLi you have to bind result fields to
        // variables before calling fetch()
        $questionidstmt->bind_result($quesid);

        // This populates $optionid
        $questionidstmt->fetch(); 

        $questionidstmt->close(); 



            foreach($value as $answer) 
            {
                $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $quesid, $answer);

                $insertanswer->execute();

                if ($insertanswer->errno) {
                    // Handle query error here
                    echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
                    break 3;
                }
            }
        }


    //close your statements at the end


    $insertanswer->close();
    $insert->close();
}

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Results from var_dump($_POST);

```
array(8) { 
["numberAnswer"]=> array(2) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "1" 
         [1]=> string(1) "1" 
         } 
         ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) 
         { 
         [0]=> string(1) "1" 
         [1]=> string(1) "2" 
         } 
         ["questionText"]=> array(2) { 
         [0]=> string(12) "What is 2+2?" 
         [1]=> string(12) "What is 4+4?" 
         } 
         ["gridValues"]=> array(2) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "4" 
         [1]=> string(1) "4" 
         } 
         ["reply"]=> array(2) { 
         [0]=> string(6) "single" 
         [1]=> string(6) "single" 
         } 
         ["textWeight"]=> array(2) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "5" 
         [1]=> string(1) "5" 
         } 
         ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" ["value"]=> array(2) { 
         [1]=> array(1) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "B" 
         } 
         [2]=> array(1) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "D" 
         } 
         } 
         }
```

Comment: You should ask a question in a way that it applies to others, too. For example, I normally do not care about QuestionIDs, I find that very uninteresting but I might use other IDs. Just a hint.

Comment: Can you please show me what value you are passing for Questionid and answer?

Comment: @hakre I will edit question later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your QuestionID is coming from `$_POST['value']`, which is probably not what you want... you need to get the automatically generated QuestionID from mysql after each question is inserted.

You can retrieve the last generated ID using `$mysqli->insert_id`. Do this after each call to `$insert->execute();`, then use those IDs when you go to insert your answers.

### Edit 1:

You should be using `$mysqli->insert_id`, because `insert_id` is only valid on a connection object (yours is called `$mysqli`).

You also need to assign the insert_id to something. I'm having trouble following your code but I think what you want is to store question IDs in an array for later use, something like this:

```
$question_ids[$i] = $mysqli->insert_id
```

I'm at a loss for what you're trying to do after this, I guess you pull in some answers with a corresponding question number but... perhaps if you can post the output of `var_dump($_POST)` we will understand a bit better. In any case you will need some kind of a loop that inserts the answers for each question, and you can (hopefully) use the array `$question_ids[$i]` to retrieve the QuestionIDs.

### Edit 2:

Here is some sample code (untested), try to get this working before getting fancy with `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`

```
<?php
$questions = array(
    array(2, 1),
    array(2, 2),
    # etc
);
$answers = array(
    array(A, C),
    array(A, B),
);

$questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionNo) VALUES (?, ?)";  
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
    die('couldn\'t prepare statement 1');
}

$answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (QuestionId, Answer) VALUES (?, ?)";
if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
    die('couldn\'t prepare statement 2');
}

$c = count($questions);

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++)
{
    $insert->bind_param("ii", $questions[$i][0], $questions[$i][1]);
    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->errno) 
    {
        die("Error inserting question $i");
    }

    $lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;

    foreach ($ans in $answers[$i])
    {
        $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $lastID, $ans);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
            die("Error inserting answer to question $i");
        }
    }

}

$insertanswer->close();
$insert->close();
?>
```

Comment: Do I need to change this to $insert->insertid as it refers to the `$insert` INSERT or does it have to be `$mysqli->insert_id`? Also shall I just change variable `$lastID` to = `$insert->insertid` or `$mysqli->insert_id`?

Comment: I think I am calling $insert->insertid() in wrong place when inserting them because it only inserts for last questionId only for all answers. Updated question

Comment: Yeah  I am trying to pull out answers for each question

Comment: That's correct. QuestionID is auto generated by MySQL, hence it isn't known until *after* MySQL inserts into the Question table. You've put my latest code in the wrong place... I think you should simplify your code to the bare minimum and work up from there, see my latest edit

Comment: It is still doing same thing, still only inserting answers for the last questioId only. Can we do it this way, the original way I tried where we do a SELECT query to find each questionId which belongs to each question number within a sessionId. I think I prefer it that way

Comment: rollback question to original code. The mysqli->insertid will help for toher people but for me I think I prefer the SELECT query way

Comment: The problem is that we can't see your `$_POST` variable, so we can't understand what data you are receiving and processing. I can't help you further without this information. Please post either `var_dump($_REQUEST); var_dump($_SESSION)`, or include the client side code (HTML or whatever)

Comment: Sure, give me 10 mins to post this, but I like to do it the SELECT query method.

Comment: included results of var dump in my question